# Comments and ratings for publishing pages

Tags: 2013, comments, content-rating

What's the best way to enable comments and ratings for publishing pages in SharePoint 2013? Is there an app / add in for that?

I don't want to use tags and notes as it's deprecated and no longer available in future versions of SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

We built our own following [this excellent tutorial](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/1/26/using-spservices-to-create-discussion-and-reply-in-a-discuss.html) by John Liu.

Basically it uses [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) and jquery to handle reading from and writing to a "hidden" discussion list. It could be done with SPServices, but you would need to write your own CAML and SOAP, so I would recommend using it.

I've been meaning to update to the new 2013 REST api, but there are some fiddly issues with responses to comments so I haven't worked that all out yet.

Basically you create a "hidden" discussion list. Which you use SPServices (or REST if you're brave) to read from and write to the list. You might need a unique lookup key such as the url or in our case we used document id service. This is used by the query to retrieve threads related to just the page you are on.

As for ratings I'm not sure. We are using cross-site publishing and have created a remote list which fake list items to serve as the proxy for ratings. Perhaps that is another question which needs some more explanation.

Answer (score -2):

here is another workaround, adding the controls in your page layouts.

- create a new page layout and click on it.
- In your page layout, paste    in these snippets where you'd like the
  comments and ratings to    reside.

Comments

```
<div class="comments">  
<!--CS: Start Comments Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointPortalControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>-->
<!--SPM:<div class="article-content">-->
<!--SPM:Comment on this article:-->
<!--SPM:<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl 
        ID="CommentControl" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:</div>-->
<!--CE: End Comments Snippet-->             
</div>
```

Ratings

```
<div class="ratings">
<!--CS: Start Rating Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointPortalControls" 
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" 
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>-->
<!--SPM:   <SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl 
    ID="PageRatingControl" 
    FieldName="AverageRating" 
    runat="server"/>-->
<!--CE: End Rating Snippet-->
</div>
```

[Add Comments and Ratings to a SharePoint 2013 Page Layout Using Design Manager](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2014/10/19/add-comments-and-ratings-to-a-sharepoint-2013-page-layout-using-design-manager.aspx)

https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/likes-rating-and-comments-on-sharepoint-pages/